# How can I move the expression down from numerator in TeXForm?

Tags: output-formatting, latex, output

```
In[1]:=f[n]/9 // TeXForm
Out[1]//TeXForm=\frac{f(n)}{9}
```

but I need `\frac{1}{9}f(n)` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[n] Defer[1/9] // TeXForm
```

> ```
> \frac {1} {9} f (n)
> ```

Slightly more genearally,

```
ClearAll[deferRationalsAndPowers]
deferRationalsAndPowers = ReplaceAll[r : (_Rational | Power[_, -1]) :> Defer[r]];


expr = h[n]/9 + w[a]/b
```

[image]

```
deferRationalsAndPowers @ expr
```

[image]

```
TeXForm @ deferRationalsAndPowers @ expr
```

> ```
> \frac{1}{b} w(a)+\frac{1}{9} h(n)
> ```

```
expr2 = 1/2 f[a]^6 + 3/4 f[b]^2 + 8/9 f[c]
```

[image]

```
deferRationalsAndPowers @ expr2
```

[image]

```
TeXForm @ deferRationalsAndPowers @ expr2
```

> ```
> \frac{1}{2} f(a)^6+\frac{3}{4} f(b)^2+\frac{8}{9} f(c)
> ```

Comment: If the input is an expression, how can I add 'defer' to the coefficients.

Comment: For example, the input is `1/2 f[a]^6 + 3/4 f[b]^2 + 8/9 f[c]` , how to add 'defer' before each 'f[]' o(TωT)o

Comment: @Patchouli, please see the update.